# Getting stuck when CallableStatement is executing at SpringBoot application

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, callable-statement

When I run my `CallableStatement` to PL/SQL DB it is getting stuck. I think it is a main thread problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

My `OracleService` class:

```
@Service
public class OracleService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleService.class);

    private static final String PROCEDURE = "{ call <USER>.<PACKAGE>.<PROCEDURE_NAME>(?, ?) }";

    @Autowired
    private OracleConfig oracleConfig;

    public void testProcedure() {

        try (Connection connection = oracleConfig.connection()) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);

            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(PROCEDURE);

            int index = 1;

            Date currDate = new Date();
            callableStatement.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(currDate.getTime()));
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(index++, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

            callableStatement.execute(); // Here it is getting stuck

            // Processing data
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And it is called by simple `CommandLineRunner` in `Application` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner lookup() {
        return args -> {
                    OracleService service = new OracleService();
                    service.testProcedure();
         };
    }
}
```

If anyone knows please help me)

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem in the stored procedure itself rather than a problem in the code that calls it?

Comment: If the procedure is modifying data then it could just be blocked by uncommitted changes in another session; e.g. if you created test data through a client (SQL Developer etc.) but haven't committed before trying to call the procedure from your application. See if you've left anything in that state; there are queries you can run in the DB if you aren't sure and can't find anything.

Comment: You are using Spring and Spring Boot why aren't you using a `JdbcTemplate` to execute the code. You are opening connections outside the scope of Spring, leading to connection leaks. Next to that your code posted here simply cannot work as you are creating a new instance of `OracleService` and call methods on that.

Comment: @M.Deinum as mentioned guys above, the problem was related with silly uncommitted changes. Yes, `JdbcTemplate` is better idea, thank you! I'm moving on it. By the way, the code is working. But, anyway it is a bad use case)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for people who response on comments. The silly problem was related with an SQL statement waiting for updates in my client. Be careful =)

P.S.: as @M.Deinum mentioned, when you use Spring better practice is retrieving `Connection`s from `JdbcTemplate`'s pool

Comment: No it isn't better to retrieve `Connection` s from the pool inside the `JdbcTemplate` you should properly use the `JdbcTemplate` using `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()` is the same bad idea as you had in your original code.

Comment: @M.Deinum you mean better would be to execute `SQL` using `JdbcTemplate`? Can you explain in detail, please

Comment: Use the  `execute`, `update` methods to execute the query and let Spring do the resource handling. Your code can be trimmed down by 60% and without you having to open/close/commit connections/resultssets/statements. Spring will do all that for you.